# Give more score to documents that contains all query terms

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, information-retrieval

I have a problem with scoring in elasticsearch. When user enter a query that contains 3 terms, sometimes a document that has two words a lot, outscores a document that contains all three words. for example if user enters "elasticsearch query tutorial", I want documents that contains all these words score higher than a document with a lot of "tutorial" and "elasticsearch" terms in it.

PS: I am using minimum should match and shingls in my query. also they made ranking a lot better, they did not solve this problem completely. I need something like query coordination in lucene's practical scoring function. is there anything like that in elastic with BM-25?

Comment: in your case, would you consider the phrase to be matched?

Comment: @bhoo-day Not necessarily. I am using phrase matching and it helps ranking a lot but it does not solve my current problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions could be using [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html):

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": { "match_all": {} },
          "functions": [
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "title": "elasticserch" } },
                  "weight": 1
              },
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "title": "tutorial" } },
                  "weight": 1
              }
          ],
          "score_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, you would have clearly a better position for documents with more matches. However, this would completely ignore TF-IDF or any other parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not want to ignore TF-IDF completely.